# How do I use jetbrains exposed with android contentResolver/Mediastore

Tags: android, kotlin, orm, android-contentresolver, kotlin-exposed

Im trying to make a simple android mediaplayer app that can be controlled from a distance. At the moment I'm trying to fix the issue of sending all the information on artists/albums/songs that are on the phone. At the moment I'm retrieving all the information as such:

```
private val contentResolver = activity.contentResolver!!

fun getAll():Set<Album>{
    val res = mutableSetOf<Album>()
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            arrayOf(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST)
            ,null,null)
    if(cursor!!.moveToFirst())
        do {
            res.add(Album().apply {
                name = cursor.getString(0)
                if (!cursor.getString(1).isNullOrEmpty())
                    albumArtUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(1))
                songCount = cursor.getInt(2)
                artist = Artist().apply {
                    name = cursor.getString(3)
                }
            })
            cursor.moveToNext()
        }while (!cursor.isAfterLast)
    cursor.close()
    return res
}
```

Seeing that I'm using a cursor, I thought I was working with a kind of database (SQLite or so) As you can see, this is a lot of code for just a set of objects with little information; the album objects created don't have the songs in them. For this you'd need to start a new query, starting and a new URI. Now I thought I could use an ORM. So I can actually fill the album objects with a list of songs and so on. I decided to try Jetbrains Exposed, typed:

```
 val database = Database.connect(....)
```

and I'm at a loss, I don't know how to connect to this the database. I can't seem to find any examples on how to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposed is for JDBC. `ContentResolver` is not using JDBC, and the `Cursor` is not an object from JDBC. In general, Android does not use JDBC, in apps or at the OS level.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guess I'll look into ORMLite the I guess

Comment: @Typhaon: I am not aware of any ORMs for Android that target accessing a `ContentProvider` through a `ContentResolver`. In general, Android ORMs and similar frameworks (e.g., Room) are for accessing your own SQLite database.